# how to improve the efficiency of finding clusters in python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, cluster-computing, depth-first-search

Right now the project I'm doing is about percolation, which is described as follow:
There are N disks with radius r randomly distributed on a unit. If the disks are close enough (within 2r), then they are connected. Connected disks form cluster, and as the density of the disk increase, there will be more clusters formed. Once the density reaches a threshold value, two opposite side of the square area will be connected by the cluster. My task is to figure out that threshold value.

Now my algorithm is as follow:

1. I use `np.random.uniform` to create a Nx2 array that stores the N coordinates.
2. I create a function `findoverlap(coordinates_array, r)` that use a loop to check the distance between two points (if there are N points, then there are N(N-1) checking, since for each points I check all the other N-1 points), and if the distance is short enough, I store the coordinates in a dictionary.
   e.g. `{0:[1,2],1:[0,3],2:[0],3[1]}` means disk 0 is connected to disk 1 and 2, disk 1 is connected to disk 0 and 3, etc.
3. I use depth-first search to return the list of cluster based on the dictionary created previously.
4. For each cluster, I use a loop to check each point's coordinates to see if it is connected to one side of the wall. Once I have found two points that connect the whole cluster to the two sides, I move on to check the next cluster.
5. For each value of N, I repeat the whole simulation many times to calculate the probability P for that density to result in a successful connection of the two sides. Then I vary N and to get a relationship between the density and P so I can find the threshold.

Since I want to try to simulate an infinite system, I need to make r as small as possible. For r=0.02 (the square area is of unit length) and N of 1000, repeating the simulation 50 times need about 20mins.

- How can I improve the code and make it more efficient?
- Are there any better algorithms that I can use?

By the way the course I'm having is for 1st yr phys students with no prior programming experience, and I've already done all the essential tasks for this project. I guess I don't need to make anything too fancy, but still I would like to make it as good as possible.

Comment: Nice question! Can't you express your data using graph theory? See http://networkx.github.io/